# process.binding is not supported, browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, dust.js

In a project where I am using Gulp and Browserify, anytime I try to require dust library (dustjs) in my script, Browserify throws an error: "process.binding is not supported".

Note: Browserify throws the same error whether dust is Installed from npm or called in  and added via 'browserify-shim' in package.json.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Browserify only shims certain common Node-specific properties. As said in the [process documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/process):

> This module mostly exists to provide the nextTick functionality and nothing more. We keep this module lean because it will often be included by default by tools like browserify when it detects a module has used the process global.

It also defines a few other properties to prevent `undefined` errors from being thrown. `binding` and `chdir` intentionally throw errors, however.